# How to write a SWAR comparison which puts 0xFF in a lane on matches?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, swar

I'm trying to write a SWAR compare-for-equality operation, working on `uint64_t` pretending to be 8 'lanes' of `uint8_t`. The closest I've managed to achieve, based on techniques in Hacker's Delight and Bit Twiddling Hacks, is the following:

```c
uint64_t compare_eq (uint64_t x, uint64_t y) {
    uint64_t xored = x ^ y;
    uint64_t mask = 0x7F * 0x0101010101010101ULL;
    uint64_t tmp = (xored & mask) + mask;
    return ~(tmp | xored | mask);
}
```

However, this puts `0x80` into 'lanes' which match, and `0x00` into 'lanes' that don't, whereas I want `0xFF` in 'lanes' that match, and `0x00` in 'lanes' that don't. Is it possible to write this without branching?

Comment: Once you have byte-wide MSBs, (so `0x80` or `0x00` per byte lane) right shift by 7 then multiply with `0xff` (255).

Comment: @njuffa That looks like a (decent) *answer*, to me.

Comment: @njuffa: Which is equivalent to `(x << 1) - (x >> 7)`, if you don't trust your compiler to figure that out for you.

Comment: @NateEldredge `x << 1` will overflow if the top lane is 0x80

Comment: @phuclv: Yes, but the result is correct regardless (unsigned overflow is well defined in C).  In that case the top lane will be subtracting 1 from 0 which is 0xff as desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record, this is just a variant for calculating a high bit in nonzero bytes (one instruction less) put together with the comments from @njuffa and @Nate Eldredge (probably slightly more efficient than in 4386427's answer).

```
uint64_t compare_eq (uint64_t x, uint64_t y) {
    uint64_t xored = x ^ y;
    uint64_t mask = ((((xored >> 1) | 0x8080808080808080) - xored) & 0x8080808080808080);
    return (mask << 1) - (mask >> 7);
}
```

Comment: Whoops, I forgot I had to invert the logic of which kind of byte maps to 0 and which to 0x80. Hopefully fixed now.

Comment: Actually no that was not the problem. Can you please give an example of an input that gives a wrong result?

Comment: OK I get it now, hopefully actually fixed. Sorry for the confusion :-/

Answer (score 1):

To start with there is a bug (a typo?) in the posted code:

```
uint64_t mask = 0x7F * 0x0101010101010101ULL;
                       ^^
                    Missing 0x
```

Once you have either 0x80 or 0x00 in the lanes, you can divide by 0x80 and multiply by 0xff.

Like:

```
uint64_t compare_eq (uint64_t x, uint64_t y) {
    uint64_t xored = x ^ y;
    uint64_t mask = 0x7F * 0x0101010101010101ULL;
    uint64_t tmp = (xored & mask) + mask;
    uint64_t res = ~(tmp | xored | mask);
    res = res / 0x80;
    res = res * 0xff;
    return res;
}
```